# Can't get WpfMediaKit to work

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-mediakit

I've discovered [WpfMediaKit](https://github.com/Sascha-L/WPF-MediaKit) which seems like a good alternative to `<MediaElement>`. However, I can't seem to get it to work.

In Visual Studio I create a new WPF project, then I downloaded the [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPFMediaKit/). I add the `xmlns` and a player element, and assign a source to the element and start the application... but nothing happens. Nothing is displayed, no errors.

```
<Window x:Class="MainApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MainApp"
    xmlns:wpfmediakit="clr-namespace:WPFMediaKit.DirectShow.Controls;assembly=WPFMediaKit"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <wpfmediakit:MediaUriElement Source="https://domain/path/video.mp4" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Downloading the file and using the local copy, by changing the source to `file://C:/Temp/File.mp4`, doesn't help a bit.

I feel like I must be missing something essential, but what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens to me as well and the problem was I didn't install the codecs the best free codec available in my opinion is Klite just download and install and everything will work fine

Comment: The mp4 file can play just fine in Windows Media Player, browsers, Quicktime Player, etc, so the codecs should already be installed.

Comment: Do you get LAV kind of icon on system tray

Comment: Not sure what "LAV" is, but I get no additional icons in the system tray

Comment: I still suggest you to install klite and restart your pc, this is the only solution I can think of.

Comment: For some reason, installing codecs does actually work. I don't believe WPF-MediaKit should have this limitation, though, so I've posted an issue at their Github project. Thanks for the help, though :)

Comment: Glad to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

- Operation System version：Win7，Win10？

  Some video type file can not play with default codec in Win7.
- You can build build filter graph with a app, [Graph Studio Next](https://github.com/cplussharp/graph-studio-next), then rebuild it in your solution.
- Use the code below to save the filter graph in your solution, then find out what's the difference between your filter graph and the filter graph from graphStudioNext.

`c#
FilterGraphTools.SaveGraphFile(filterGraph, System.IO.Path.Combine(GraphFileSaveFolderPath, $"Graph{Guid.NewGuid():N}.grf"));`